# How to ensure sign-off of user when MS Word is closed in Word Add-in with Office.js?

Tags: office365, office-js, office-addins, word-addins, word-web-addins

User is not signing off after the MS Word is closed in Addin.

We are creating a Word Add in and having a sign-in modal to sign. After the sign-in is successful and if the user closes the Word without signing off. After sometimes if user opens the Word and click on the task panel the user is still signed in. We need the user to sign-off when he closes the MS-Word. Is there anyway to use Office.js?

Comment: Are you talking about Single-Sign On feature? What mechanism is used in your add-in to sign in?

Comment: Do you call the `getAccessToken` method form the task pane?

Comment: Yes, we use the SSO feature.

Comment: See my post about that.

Answer (score 0):

The Office JavaScript API doesn't provide anything for the sign off process.  The token is managed by the host application. In case of SSO used in your add-in the code typically does the following:

1. The code calls the Office.js API `getAccessToken`. If the user is already signed in to Office, the Office host will return the access token with the claims of the signed in user.
2. If the user is not signed in, the Office host application opens a dialog box for the user to sign in. Office redirects to the Microsoft identity platform to complete the sign-in process.
3. If this is the first time the current user has used your add-in, they are prompted to consent.
4. The Office host application requests the access token from the Microsoft identity platform for the current user.
5. The Microsoft identity platform returns the access token to Office. Office will cache the token on your behalf so that future calls to `getAccessToken` simply return the cached token.
6. The Office host application returns the access token to the add-in as part of the result object returned by the `getAccessToken` call.
7. The token is both an access token and an identity token. You can use it as an identity token to parse and examine claims about the user, such as the user's name and email address.

Your code doesn't have access how and when the token is expired unlike standalone web applications where you could mark it expired or make the sign off calls, see [Single Sign-Out SAML Protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/single-sign-out-saml-protocol) and [A web app that calls web APIs: Remove accounts from the token cache on global sign-out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-call-api-sign-in?tabs=aspnetcore) for more information.

You can post or vote for an existing feature request on [Tech Community](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions) where they are considered when the Office dev team goes through the planning process.